Espacio adicional después de comentarios HTML en VS Code rompe la indentación
Estoy enfrentando un problema con el editor VS Code.
Resulta que al escribir un comentario en HTML (<!-- comentario -->) y luego agregar contenido en la línea siguiente, se inserta un espacio adicional al principio de la nueva línea. Este comportamiento rompe la estructura de mi HTML y resulta muy molesto.
Ejemplo del problema:
<div>
  <!-- test fallido -->
   <p>Este es el problema</p> <!-- Hay un espacio adicional antes de la etiqueta <p> -->
</div>

<div>
  <!-- test valido -->
  <p>Aqui esta bien</p> <!-- No hay espacio adicional antes de la etiqueta <p> -->
</div>

Archivo ".editorconfig" actual:
# Editor configuration, see https://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.ts]
quote_type = single

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

Pasos que he intentado:

Ajustar insert_final_newline a false en el archivo .editorconfig.
Desactivar trim_trailing_whitespace en el archivo .editorconfig.
Desactivar el formato automático en guardado ("editor.formatOnSave":
false) en la configuración de VS Code.
Verificar y desactivar extensiones relacionadas con el formato de
HTML.

Cabe recalcar que nunca tuve este problema hasta hace poco, en este proyecto estoy usando Angular e Ionic en su última versión.
¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionar este problema?
Agradecería cualquier ayuda para evitar que se inserte este espacio adicional después de los comentarios en HTML en VS Code.

Seguro que es espacio y no la identacion de Prettier? He experimentado estos cambios al cambiar de formateo de Prettier al editor de HTML por defecto.
